# Building url with query parameters for Angular 2 Location

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have implemented a SearchComponent where the user can modify parameters like search terms and facets for filtering down results. I wish to update the url with the currently selected parameters so the user can bookmark or email the link.

My question is about updating the url to **include** parameters. I know I should be using `Location` service and specifically the `go()` method but I cannot seem to figure out which method(s) to use to take my collection of parameters (either an array or a JavaScript object) and turn that into an appropriately formatted query string based on the current `LocationStrategy`. Am I supposed to loop through the collection and concatenate the values directly to build out the single string?

Code Snippets

After posting this I have continued with playing around with the API. As I understand it, using `HashLocationStrategy` and given the following url

```
#/search
```

the output of `this.location.path(false)` is

```
/search
```

(as a side note, the output of `this.location.path(true)` is **also** `/search`)

When I use `Routing` to change the url to

```
#/search;searchTerms=ftp
```

the output of `this.location.path(false)` logically (kind of) becomes

```
/search;searchTerms=ftp
```

I have several points of concern

1. As stated before, building out the url *seems* to require me to concatenate name value pairs instead of providing a helper method that handles it for you.
2. Right now, a given component is ignorant of the route used to instantiate said component. The actual route depends on what you put in the Router Config. But now, in order to update the route I cannot just say "add this particular to current route", I actually need to extract that prefix from the current url to use in the updated url.
3. Related to item #2, I actually need to take the value returned from `path()` and split it or get the index to the `;` character so I can re-use the non-parameters portion?

Ultimately, in my mind, a component updating the path based on changes within the component *seems* to be a **very common** use-case yet the API *seems* to make it very inconvenient and a ugly manual process. I hope I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if you REALLY wanted to take another approach, you can use `encodeURIComponent(btoa(JSON.stringify(object)))` to generate the query string and
`JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(string)))` to get it back into an object...

But I'd recommend looping, as you said.

Comment: The problem I am having with modifying the url was not just building parameters. I updated the post to better explain all my (related) questions about the Location service and API (or lack of...)